# One node decision tree in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, decision-tree

Im using matlab 2014a and I cant find how to do 1 node decision tree (and 2 nodes, 3 nodes ext.) 
Itried to use:

> "MaxNumSplits",and "MaxDepth"

but I got

> MaxNumSplits is not a valid parameter name.

thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Matlab is too old for manipulating the `MaxNumSplits` parameter.

Matlab's way of implementing algorithms changes along time. This is the case here for `fitctree` (fit classification tree) when the R2015a version was released. See the [following 'new features' page](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/release-notes-R2015a.html) introducing 2 new parameters for the  `fitctree` function

> Additional option to control decision tree depth using 'MaxNumSplits' argument in fitctree, fitrtree, and templateTree functions

You can search such evolution by comparing the different versions of the docs here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html